# Undefined Variable i when creating a for loop in common lisp

Tags: undefined, common-lisp

I am having a problem getting my solution to project euler problem one to compile, SLIME gives me the error "Undefined variable 'i'" and I have no idea how to solve it hand have been searching for a solution.

```
(defun sol1 (natnum)
   (loop for i from 1 to (1- natnum))
   do (if (or (zerop (mod sum i 3))
              (zerop (mod sum i 5)))
          (incf sum i))
   sum)
```

Comment: If you were actually indenting the code correctly, you were seeing that the parentheses are wrongly placed. In programming, correct code indenting and formatting is very important for the developer, to make sure he or she understands the code.

Comment: Additionally the variable `sum` is undefined.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The variable `i` is local to the `loop` expression. The `if` is outside that loop, so the variable no longer exists.

You also haven't declared or initialized the variable `sum`. But `loop` can do summing by itself, so you don't need it.

And you're giving too many arguments to the `mod` function, it just takes two arguments. I'm not sure why you have `sum` in there.

```
(defun sol1 (natnum) 
  (loop for i from 1 to (1- natnum)
        when (or (zerop (mod i 3))
                 (zerop (mod i 5)))
            sum i))
```

Since you're using SLIME, you must be using Emacs. It has built-in Lisp indentation support, so you should use that to see the structure of your code.